# How to determine if a cell in an Excel sheet has an error alert in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, excel, typescript, npm

I have been looking through various npm packages for working with Excel files. So far I have found none that have the ability to determine if a given cell in a data sheet has an alert carrot (green triangle shown in the image below). I am not interested in fixing the error, I am merely interested in determining if a given cell has an alert present.

Does anyone know if there is a way to determine this in JavaScript? Much appreciated!

[image: Number Stored as Text Alert]